# Load and display QString with proper encoding

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, qfile

I am trying to load a name from file that has several special characters and if it is in file (looks like meno: Marek Ružička/) display it. Code here:

```
QFile File("info/"+meno+".txt");
File.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QVariant Data(File.readAll());
QString in = Data.toString(), pom;
if(in.contains("meno:")){
pom = in.split("meno:").at(1);
pom=pom.split("/").at(0);
ui->label_meno->setText(trUtf8("Celé meno: ")+pom);}
```

the part trUtf8("Celé meno: ") displays well but I cant find how to display string in pom, it alone looks like Marek  RuÅ¾iÄka, using toUtf8() function makes it Marek  RuÃÂ¾iÃÂka, I've tried to convert it to stdString too but doesn't work either. I am not sure if the conversion from QFile to QVariant and to QString is right, if this causes problem how to read data properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
QTextCodec* utf = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
QByteArray data = <<INPUT QBYTEARRAY>>.toUtf8();
QString utfString = utf->toUnicode(data);
qDebug() << utfString;
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the right ways is to use `QTextStream` for the reading, and then you can specify the codec for utf 8 as follow:

```
in.setCodec("UTF-8");
```

See the documentation for further details:

> [void QTextStream::setCodec(const char * codecName)](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qtextstream.html#setCodec-2)
>
> Sets the codec for this stream to the QTextCodec for the encoding specified by codecName. Common values for codecName include "ISO 8859-1", "UTF-8", and "UTF-16". If the encoding isn't recognized, nothing happens.

```
Example:

QTextStream out(&file);
out.setCodec("UTF-8");
```

Another right way would be to fix your current code without using `QTextStream` by using the [dedicated QString method](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qstring.html#fromUtf8) as follows:

```
QString in = QString::fromUtf8(File.readAll()), pom;
```

Please note that though you may wish to add more error handling into your code than available now.